# RedBean Php PDOException

Tags: php, mysql, redbean

I have a client who is getting the error:

**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX' (4)' in /htdocs/library/rb.php:65**

The really odd thing here is that it's not consistent... I can't even reproduce the error. Hitting refresh will, apparently, always bring requested page up without problems.

What could be causing this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the windows server does not have PDO mysql drivers installed.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you look at the mysql database, users table. Looks like the issue is specific to the host attempting to access the server.

Database users have the following 3 fields, username, password and host. Make sure the host for the user attempting to authenticate matches the IP of the machine trying to connect, or set it to % which is a wildcard.

Comment: It's even simpler than that. The site is running on a shared server. The host, dbname, username, and password supplied to R::setup() are just strings, not even variables pulled out of a config file. There's no way those are wrong, or the connection would fail every time.

Comment: That is looking in the wrong spot. Look at your Privileges on the MySQL server itself, not the script connecting to it.